# Template to match custom functors or stod, stoi, etc

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to store key-value parameters as `string` in a class named `ModelConfig`. Then I would like to automatically convert these values into specific types, either with custom conversion function or with standard functions `stod`, `stof`, `stoi`, and the like.

My class successfully parses parameters if I provide a custom conversion function, but I can't figure how to also accept standard functions. This is my approach:

```
class ModelConfig
{
public:
    ModelConfig(void) = default;

    void addParam(std::string pname, std::string pvalue) {
        m_params[pname] = pvalue;
    }

    template <class F, typename... Args, class T = typename std::result_of<F&&(const std::string&, Args...)>::type>
    T getParam(std::string pname, F&& pconv_functor) const
    {
        return pconv_functor(m_params.at(pname));
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_params;
};
```

The class above, can be tested with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include "ModelConfig.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    ModelConfig mc;
    mc.addParam("p1_float",  "123.4");
    mc.addParam("p2_double", "56.7");
    mc.addParam("p3_bool",   "true");
    mc.addParam("p4_int",    "-321");

    auto functord = [](const std::string& s) {
        return std::stod(s);
    };

    std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double", functord) << "\n";  // OK.
    std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double", std::stod) << "\n"; // Error.

    return 0;
}
```

How can I modify `getParam` to accept functions where their first argument is a `string` but which can have others with default values?

Comment: Note that you may simplify your code with `template <class F>
    auto getParam(std::string pname, F&& pconv_functor) const -> decltype(pconv_functor(std::declval<std::string>()))
    {
        return pconv_functor(m_params.at(pname));
    }` (and you may even replace `std::declval<std::string>()` by `pname` even if it might be a little misleading).

Answer (score 3):

`std::stod` is overloaded, thus the compiler can't deduce which function to use.

You can use macro to write a generic wrapper:

```
#define wrapper(f) \
    ( [] (auto&&... args) -> decltype(auto) { \
      return f(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); \
      } )
```

Then call it by:

```
std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double", wrapper(std::stod)) << "\n";
```

Comment: That's nice, but would only supported in C++14 or later.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative and, IMO, better design is to store values as `std/boost::variant<bool, long, double, std::string>` and convert it to/from string during I/O. This also detects config file errors early on load, rather than on first value access which could happen much later and crash your application in front of the user.

---

Requiring the user of this API to always pass a conversion function is cumbersome. You can use [`boost::lexical_cast`](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.lexical_cast) for converting strings to `T`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

struct ConvertProxy {
    std::string const* value_;

    template<class T>
    T as() const {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(*value_);
    }

    template<class T>
    operator T() const {
        return this->as<T>();
    }
};

class ModelConfig {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m_params;
public:
    void addParam(std::string pname, std::string pvalue) {
        m_params[pname] = pvalue;
    }

    ConvertProxy getParam(std::string pname) const {
        return {&m_params.at(pname)};
    }
};

int main() {
    ModelConfig mc;
    mc.addParam("p1_float",  "123.4");
    mc.addParam("p2_double", "56.7");
    mc.addParam("p3_bool",   "true");
    mc.addParam("p4_int",    "-321");

    // Example syntax.
    double d1 = mc.getParam("p2_double");
    auto d2 = mc.getParam("p2_double").as<double>();
    auto d3 = static_cast<double>(mc.getParam("p2_double"));
    std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double").as<double>() << "\n";
    std::cout << static_cast<double>(mc.getParam("p2_double")) << "\n";
}
```

The interface of `boost::lexical_cast` enables an easy solution here. If you cannot use `boost::lexical_cast` you should probably code up your own with a similar interface.

Comment: @MooingDuck I find your view rather limited.

Comment: @CarlesAraguz added a solution for you.

Comment: @MooingDuck Done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with no third party lib and without using preprocessor directives if you need:

- by explicitely casting your standard functions pointers. Standard functions are overloaded for `string` and `wstring` so the compiler needs our help to determine which one to apply
- and by slightly changing your functor's signature to adapt it to the signature of these standard functions as they have a second parameter.

These changes would be slight actually:

In `ModelConfig`:

```
class ModelConfig
{
[...]

    // Adapted the functor's signature to comply to standard functions' signatures:
    template <class F, typename... Args, class T = typename std::result_of<F && (const std::string&, size_t *)>::type>
    T getParam(std::string pname, F&& pconv_functor) const
    {
        return pconv_functor(m_params.at(pname), 0);
    }

[...]    
};
```

In `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
[...]

    // Adapted the functor to standard functions' signature
    auto functord = [](const std::string& s, size_t * pos) {
        return std::stod(s, pos);
    };

    // Unchanged, no need
    std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double", functord) << "\n";  // Still OK.

    // Cast to determine which overload to use. The typedef helps having things readable.
    typedef double(*StandardFunctionSignature)(const std::string&, size_t*);

    std::cout << mc.getParam("p2_double", static_cast<StandardFunctionSignature>(std::stod)) << "\n"; // NO Error, it works now.

[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the signature of the passed in overload set, you can make an additional overload that captures a specific function pointer from that set.

```
template <class F>
auto getParam(std::string pname, F&& pconv_functor) const
{
    return pconv_functor(m_params.at(pname));
}

template <class F>
auto getParam(std::string pname, F(*pconv_functor)(const std::string&, std::size_t*)) const
{
    return pconv_functor(m_params.at(pname), 0);
}
```

This has some obvious limitations, but can be useful in certain situations.

Comment: Yep, that's also a possibility but I'm looking at different alternatives right now, because I already had 6 different overloads for `getParam` (not shown in the question for the sake of simplicity)